# Format numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am getting the following formatting:

[image]

The formula I am using is the following:

```
=K18 & " - " & K19
```

The base number I am taking are:

[image]

I would like to have the following output:

[image]

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the formula TEXT to format it as required:

```
=TEXT(K18;"0") & " - " & TEXT(K19;"0")
```

If you want to make 17.646 a 17 instead of an 18, you can use the ROUNDDOWN formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(K18;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=INT(K18/1000)&" - "&INT(K19/1000)
```

This is assuming the comma separates thousands, rather than being a decimal indication.